# Restore root access CloudVPS Server

Tags: ssh

I have a VPS on CloudVPS that I used to access through SSH with RSA keys. The server is running Nginx. However, [Coda 2](https://panic.com/coda/) corrupted the folder holding the keys, making me unable to access my VPS.

CloudVPS has an online console and they told me I need to use that to regain access to my server. What should I do?

I tried `# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I can't make any changes, because I can't use the arrow keys on my keyboard in the online console. Please help me.

Comment: have you tried adding an password to your account with command `passwd`?

Comment: Also, `vi` uses hjkl as movement keys when not in an insert mode (left, down, up, right respectively).  It is true that *effete* modern equivalents like `vim` let you use the arrow keys, but they'll still honour hjkl for the hideously-ancient old guard (like me!).

Answer (score 0):

I think your VPS console only supports one line commands.

Create a public key for your mac if you don't have one already. 
Try to see if you have one with this command on your mac.  `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` if it can't find any file. Try command below to create an ssh key.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "[YOUR-MAIL-ADDRESS]"
```

Then read your public key `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Go to VPS console. & run this command.

```
echo [YOUR-PUBLIC-KEY] > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

if it can't find auhorized_keys file. just create it `touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

then try to connect to your VM with `ssh -v root@YOUR-VPS-IP`